# How can I play an audio using a local asset in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, audio

So Im using the Flutter package [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) to play audio on my app, but the problem is after importing the package, it says that the play() function can't be found.

Here is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const XlyophoneApp());
}

class XlyophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const XlyophoneApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              child: const Text('Click Me'),
              onPressed: () {
                final player = AudioCache();
                player.play("note1.wav"); // Here it says that the play function is not defined
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player

Comment: Have you read getting started guide? It is well explained here: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md

Answer (score 4):

The code below is no longer valid

```
final player = AudioCache();
player.play("note1.wav");
```

Instead of the above code you can do this

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(UrlSource('note1.wave'));

// If file located in assets folder like assets/sounds/note01.wave"
await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/note1.wave'));
```

[Source](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md)

Comment: You need to define assets/sounds in pubspec.yaml:

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/sounds/

Answer (score 0):

onPressed: () { AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer(); player.play(AssetSource("note1.wav")); },